# shell script sh removing slash (/) from argument

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

How can I prevent the slash from crashing my program. My first thought is to remove the slash but if there is a better method, please let me know. I don't know if the user will pass in "dir" or "dir/". This is in sh.

```
$1="directory/"

for i in "$1"/*
do
   some code
done
```

Comment: `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Comment: ...that said, what's this about "crashing your program"? Doubling up path separators should be harmless.

Comment: The assignment to `$1` is just for illustration, to indicate that the first positional parameter has this value? (Because you can't assign to `$1`, or `1`.)

Comment: ...indeed, it would be `set -- directory/` to set a new value to $1.

Comment: On most versions of Unix, `dir/*` and `dir//*` are equivalent. The extra slash shouldn't cause an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove it if present with a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for i in "${1%/}"/*
```

which expands to `$1` with the slash removed from the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem like @Benjamin said: Do not assign to $1.
Let's check the input and assign to `dir`.

```
# 
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 directory [other parameters]"
   exit 1
fi

if [ -d "$1"]; then
   dir="${1%/}"
else
   echo "$1 is not a valid directory"
   exit 1
fi

for file in "$dir"/*
do
   some code with "${file}"
done
```